# Performing outer join that merges joined columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am performing an outer join on two DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                    'date':    [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                    'str':     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 
                    'date':    [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                    'str':     ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Q']})

pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["id","date"], how="outer")
```

This gives the result

```
   date  id str_x str_y
0     4   1     a     A
1     5   2     b     B
2     6   3     c     C
3     7   4     d     D
4     8   5     e   NaN
5     8   6   NaN     Q
```

Is it possible to perform the outer join such that the `str`-columns are concatenated? In other words, how to perform the join such that we get the DataFrame

```
   date  id     str
0     4   1     aA
1     5   2     bB
2     6   3     cC
3     7   4     dD
4     8   5     e
5     8   6     Q
```

where all `NaN` have been set to `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not, possible solution is replace `NaN`s and join together:

```
df = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["id","date"], how="outer", suffixes=('','_'))
        .assign(str=lambda x: x['str'].fillna('') + x['str_'].fillna(''))
        .drop('str_', 1))
```

Similar alternative:

```
df = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["id","date"], how="outer", suffixes=('','_'))
        .assign(str=lambda x: x.filter(like='str').fillna('').values.sum(axis=1))
        .drop('str_', 1))
```

---

```
print (df)
   date  id str
0     4   1  aA
1     5   2  bB
2     6   3  cC
3     7   4  dD
4     8   5   e
5     8   6   Q
```

Answer (score 2):

If `'id', 'date'` is unique in each data frame, then you can set the index and add the dataframes.

```
icols = ['date', 'id']
df1.set_index(icols).add(df2.set_index(icols), fill_value='').reset_index()

   date  id str
0     4   1  aA
1     5   2  bB
2     6   3  cC
3     7   4  dD
4     8   5   e
5     8   6   Q
```